# What is the use of the black ops 2 Nav cards?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

[image: Nav card]

The image above shows the icon of the nav card you can pick up on tranzit. Now from reading some on other forums i found that you can place this card on a crafting table on die riese? But there also is another nav card (the one on the image (i believe)) that does not fit on that table. My question would be: Is there any use for these cards? Are they part of an yet to be implementented easter egg? Any answers or more information would be welcome.

Cheers, Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that Buried has arrived I have found the Buried Navcard and Die Rise Navcard goes into the Buried Navcard reader and is accepted.

Going back to Tranzit, the Buried Navcard successfully inserts into the reader there.

Going to Die Rise, I pick up its Navcard expecting for the buried card to disappear, but now I have a Dual Navcard.

One from Buried and the other from either Tranzit or Die Rise are the only current combos.

The overall purpose of the cards is still a mystery, and there's nothing more you can do with them at this time.

Comment: Navcards are now complete. They are used with the 'push-button' box in Buried after successfully linking all NavCards.

Answer (score 2):

There is no use for the nav card at the moment , The Green Run NavCard can be inserted to Die Riese Nav Reader to make the Nav Reader permanent in later games . But there is no actual use for it , at least right now

Answer (score 1):

As of the time of posting there is no direct use of the NavCards. The NavCard from Transit can be accepted into the build table in Die Rise. There is no NavCard table in Mob of the Dead. When you use the Tranzit NavCard in the Tranzit NavCard Reader you get the message

> "That is the incorrect navcard!"

However when you use the Tranzit NavCard in Die Rises' Reader you get the message

> "NavCard Accepted

With absolutely no visible affect to anything within the game. As of now, this is all we know about NavCards, the rest of this answer is speculation based upon comments the developers of BOII Zombies have made.

> ! The developers have confirmed that there will be an 'end game' to BOII zombies. There is a way that the 4 main characters will be able to escape the zombie apocalypse. Further speculation leads to this happening after they have released all map packs and you have linked each map together using the Navcards. The reason that no Navcard works in the Reader in Tranzit is because after the release of the final map, the Navcard from that map will work in Tranzit's reader to enable the 'end game' content.
>
> ! The reason that there was no Navcard table in Mob of the Dead was because it did not involve the greater storyline with the 4 main characters. Similar to Call of the Dead in Black Ops I.

Comment: When i went to get the navcard at tranzit there were two to choose from after getting one and leaving the game to go back the second one that had a diff. Emblem on sceen is not there any ideas why and what it does